# Organize Firebase database for individual users, idea?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my android app, i had implemented google sign in with Firebase Auth procedures.
As:

```
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, SIGNIN_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == SIGNIN_CODE) {
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        try {
            // Authenicate with my Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this); //ProgressDialog.show(this, null, "Please wait while we load sign in..", true);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait while we load sign in..");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            Drawable drawable = new ProgressBar(this).getIndeterminateDrawable().mutate();
            drawable.setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.progress),
                                    PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
            dialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(drawable);
            dialog.show();

            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } catch (ApiException e) {
            // Google Sign In failed?
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
        }
    }
} //A lot more stuffs etc etc..
```

I already have a SQlite offline database. Now only for logged in users, i want the user can sync the SQlite database's contents with firebase database, which the user can access/sync later online.

But how to organize that single firebase database for individual signed in users with UIDs and etc.. ?

A little more specific advice/tutorial would be nice :)

Comment: Does someone have an answer to this? I'm also looking for a solution

Answer (score 1):

It can be done, you need to restrict access to data so that each user can access his/her data only by defining firebase security rules like below.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /yourrootnode/{uid} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == uid;
    }
}
```

Save user specific data from app like shown below, here dataModelObj object should contain uid field and you need to populate it from user object like dataModelObj .setUid(user.getUid());

```
  firestoreDB.collection("yourrootnode")
            .add(dataModelObj)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {

.....
```

And then you can read only user data in app like this.

```
 firestoreDB.collection("yourrootnode")
                .whereEqualTo("uid", user.getUid())
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            ....
        }
```

For more information you can check http://www.zoftino.com/android-firebase-email-password-authentication

Answer (score 0):

You can't make separate databases for each user, but you can organize your single database for multiple users.  It's conventional to set aside a node of your database for users, and use their UID from Firebase Authentication to create a space for each user.

For example, the part of your database for users could be organized like this:

```
/users
    /uid1
        /name
    /uid2
        /name
```

You would then want to protect per-user data with [user based security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security).